# Inno Setup Run code according to setup type

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to provide a couple of different installation types performing different operations to my installer: if "ApplicationServer" type is selected, only perform part of the code. If Client type is selected instead, only perform this part of the procedure.

I tried to include the 2 "blocks" of code within a function called

```
[Types]
Name: "application"; Description: "{cm:ApplicationServer}"
Name: "client"; Description: "{cm:Client}"

[CustomMessages]
ApplicationServer=Application Server:
Client=Client:
```

*If first choice selected, I want to perform a specific code made of several procedures, constant, variables to run a sequence of SQL script, while if second is chosen I need to perform some other stuffs into the code area, like this:*

```pascal
[Code]

function ApplicationServer(blabla)
begin:
  { <!This part only to run for ApplicationServer type!> }
  { following constants and variables for the ADO Connection + SQL script run }
  const
    myconstant1=blabla;
  var
    myvar1=blabla;    
  { here all the procedure to define and manage an ADO Connection to run a sql script }
  { procedure 1 }
  { procedure 2 }
end

function Client(blabla)
begin:
  { <!This part only to run for Client type!> }
  { following constants and variables only for performing some stuffs on top of client }
  const
    myconstant2=blabla;
  var
    myvar2=blabla;
  { procedure 3 }
  { procedure 4 }
end
```

Is there a way to manage a specific part of the code to run according the type of installation running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`WizardSetupType` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardsetuptype).

You will probably want to check in `CurStepChanged` [event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents).

```pascal
procedure ApplicationServer;
begin
  { procedure 1 }
  { procedure 2 }
end;

procedure Client;
begin
  { procedure 1 }
  { procedure 2 }
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  SetupType: string;
begin
  Log(Format('CurStepChanged %d', [CurStep]));

  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    SetupType := WizardSetupType(False);

    if SetupType = 'application' then
    begin
      Log('Installing application server');
      ApplicationServer;
    end
      else
    if SetupType = 'client' then
    begin
      Log('Installing client');
      Client;
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Unexpected setup type: ' + SetupType);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

The Pascal script does not support local constants, only global constants.

It's not clear anyway, what you want, if you want a local constant or initialize a global constant conditionally. You cannot do the latter anyway, a constant is constant, it cannot have a different value.

The same with your variables. *Are these local variables or do you want to set a value to a global variable conditionally?*